# IIS 6 WebService Java client (stubs generated with axis 2 )

Tags: java, wcf, service, client

I have a simple WCF WebService running on IIS 6. It returns "hello" when I call the getData function. I have java stubs for the client that I generated using axis 2. My request gets time out every time. I have increased the timeout to 5 minutes but to no effect.

Here are the logs. The client waits for 30 seconds and times out (increase in timeout does not help ) ...  Any pointers on how I can move forward ? I have access to the server as well ... 
I have webservices that connect to Tomcat that work just fine. Just this WCF one ...

```
2010-11-10 15:26:05,209 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header  - >> "POST /TestWCF/TestWCF.svc HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2010-11-10 15:26:05,225 [main] DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase  - Adding Host request header
2010-11-10 15:26:05,225 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header  - >> "Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8; action="http://tempuri.org/ITestWCF/GetData"[\r][\n]"
2010-11-10 15:26:05,225 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header  - >> "User-Agent: Axis2[\r][\n]"
2010-11-10 15:26:05,225 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header  - >> "Host: xxx.yyy.org[\r][\n]"
2010-11-10 15:26:05,225 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header  - >> "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
2010-11-10 15:26:05,225 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.header  - >> "[\r][\n]"
2010-11-10 15:26:05,225 [main] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter  - start writeTo()
2010-11-10 15:26:05,225 [main] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter  -   preserve=false
2010-11-10 15:26:05,225 [main] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter  -   isOptimized=false
2010-11-10 15:26:05,225 [main] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter  -   isDoingSWA=false
2010-11-10 15:26:05,240 [main] DEBUG org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils  - XMLStreamWriter is com.ctc.wstx.sw.SimpleNsStreamWriter
2010-11-10 15:26:05,240 [main] DEBUG org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl  - serialize {http://tempuri.org/}GetData to XMLStreamWriter
2010-11-10 15:26:05,256 [main] DEBUG org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter  - end writeTo()
2010-11-10 15:26:05,256 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.content  - >> "cf[\r][\n]"
2010-11-10 15:26:05,256 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.content  - >> "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><ns2:GetData xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/" /></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>"
2010-11-10 15:26:05,256 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.content  - >> "[\r][\n]"
2010-11-10 15:26:05,256 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.content  - >> "0"
2010-11-10 15:26:05,256 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.content  - >> "[\r][\n]"
2010-11-10 15:26:05,256 [main] DEBUG httpclient.wire.content  - >> "[\r][\n]"
2010-11-10 15:26:05,256 [main] DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod  - Request body sent
2010-11-10 15:26:35,758 [main] DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector  - Closing the connection.
2010-11-10 15:26:35,774 [main] DEBUG org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector  - Method retry handler returned false. Automatic recovery will not be attempted
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the answer to the problem lies in the server logs.

A bit of a guess, but try [disabling chunked HTTP requests](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_3/http-transport.html) (I recently had an issue sending such requests from JAX-WS to a WebService provider that did not support this).

Comment: It was wshttp thing .. The weirdest thing is IIS swallowed my message and did nothing with it.